# Use two different Versions of boost

Tags: c++, boost

i try to build a cmake which use two different version of boost. ( I use a framework which only runs with boost 1.55 but my application needs boost 1.57)

My idea was to make 2 Cmake build processes

Application Cmake boost 1.57

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Application)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fdiagnostics-color=auto -std=c++0x ")

set(Boost_DEBUG  ON)
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
set(BOOST_ROOT /opt/boost/boost_1_57)

find_package(Boost 1.57 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread filesystem log system)

include_directories(
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
SYSTEM /opt/boost/boost_1_57/include
)

ADD_LIBRARY( AppLib SHARED testVersion.cpp ...)
```

Framework Cmake boost 1.55

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(Test)

add_subdirectory(Application)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fdiagnostics-color=auto -std=c++0x ")

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{BOOST_ROOT})

find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread filesystem log system)

include_directories(
SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries( test AppLib )
```

test.cpp

```
#include "testVersion.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Main call Using Boost "
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minior version
              << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "library : " << std::endl;
    Version v;
    v.callVersion();
}
```

testVersion

```
#include "testVersion.hpp"

void Version::callVersion()

{            std::cout << "Using Boost "
                      << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
                      << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minior version
                      << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
                      << std::endl;

    }
```

testVersion.hpp

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
class Version
{
public:
    void callVersion();

};
```

If i do it this way it runs well :
Output:

```
Main call Using Boost 1.55.0
Using Boost 1.57.0
```

But when I eliminate the testVersion.cpp file and inline my callVersion I get the output:

```
Main call Using Boost 1.55.0
library : 
Using Boost 1.55.0
```

because the compiler use for the headers boost 1.55 only when i include boost in the source files he takes 1.57. How i can solve that ? is that possible?

---

Conclusion:
I need an empty header :

```
all_boost_includes.hpp
```

with a all_boost_includes.cpp

```
#include "boost..."
#include ...
```

which will just include all boost headers. And then i have to include this header in every header in my application. Is that correct?

This is similar to an precompiled boost header or?

I tried include "boost_headers.hpp" which is empty and has a boost_header.cpp which includes boost versions

I added on my Application cmake
ADD_LIBRARY( AppLib SHARED boost_headers.cpp)

But when i try

```
#include "precompiled_boost.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


class Version
{
public:
    void callVersion(){
        std::cout << "Using Boost "
                  << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
                  << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minior version
                  << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
                  << std::endl;
    }

};
```

He don't know BOOST_VERSION. What I have to do there ? If i include precompiled_boost.cpp i get the wrong output

Answer (score 0):

## 1. If you do not inline callVersion

Compiling library compiles code for `Version::callVersion` within the library. As library uses boost 1.55 `Version::callVersion` will return `1.55`.

## 2. If you do inline callVersion

Compiling library *does not* compile code for `Version::callVersion` within the library, because it will bi inlined! Your `Version::callVersion`  will actually be compiled on the `test` side. As `test` uses boost 1.57, `Version::callVersion` will return `1.57`

## Conclusion

You should not inline you calls. More, you cannot use classes that refer to any boost in their declarations in both application and library projects that use different versions of boost. If you have to, you should consider creating some proxy objects or functions, so all boost stuff will be encapsulated inside your library.

Comment: Thanks, but i think u mixed the boost Version on test when I do inline i will get 1.55 and if i not inline i get 1.57 but the explanation is clear.  I added something above is that correct? A precompiled boost header in my Application?

Comment: @Hunk If you want use different versions of boost in an application and library, you should get rid of all boost references in your library API. You should not include _any_ boost stuff to the headers that will be included by both application and library and you should not use _any_ boost functions or classes in headers that are used by both application & library.

Comment: Ok thanks, I dont think that this is possible because I have a few typedefs like boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr in headers which are necessary. Forward declaration is not possible on this point or?

Comment: Forward declarations are possible, but you can only _use_ forward declared objects (_not pointers_) inside librarry. The idea is `boost_1.5.5::shared_ptr<Foo>` and `boost_1.5.7::shared_ptr<Foo>` are **completely** different classes.

Comment: @Lol4t0 "If you want use different versions of boost in an application and library, you should ***get rid of all boost references*** in your library API." Why? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?